# Durandal optimization using weyland doesn't work with requirejs paths

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal, hottowel, weyland

I've developed a SPA website using great `HotTowel` template by John Papa.
While doing optimizations I've confront a problem. I've simplified the situation to make the question more clear.

There's some place that I use require to get a JavaScript `viewModel` like:

```
require(["myScripts/serviceRunner"], function (viewModel) {
    console.log("ViewModel loaded:" + viewModel)                            
                  });
```

At the server side, there's a controller and action which handles the http requests like:

```
http://localhost:1441/api/UL/LoadJS
```

So instead of having `require(["http://localhost:1441/api/UL/LoadJS/serviceRunner"]`. I've defined a path like:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
    "myScripts": "http://localhost:1441/api/UL/LoadJS"
    ...
```

Everything works just fine. But after optimization and creating main-built using weyland, The require cannot load the given path.

Is there any configuration that I missed for optimization?

FYI, I'm using Durandal 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Have You add "myScripts" entry in `weyland-config.js` file?

As far as I am concerned You have to add same paths You do define in `main.js` also in `weyland-config.js` in `rjs paths` part.

```
exports.config = function(weyland) {
...
   .task.rjs({
   ...
      rjs:{
      ...
      paths : { 
           "myScripts": "http://localhost:1441/api/UL/LoadJS"
           ...
           }
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: I read `rjs task` in `npm\node_modules\weyland\lib\tasks\rjs\index.js`.
weyland get the file pattern from `include: ['App/**/*.js', 'Scripts/durandal/**/*.js']`. After get, the file path like this `../Scripts/durandal/system` or `../Scripts/durandal/plugins/router`
weyland use this `paths` for correct the path. Replace  `../Scripts/durandal` with `durandal`.
But I have multi-Project and get the file from other project **not exist in main-built** with requier and mycontroller. @Krzysztof Cieslak